# zend framework empty form after submit

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form based on Zend_Form.
When form isn't valid, my inputs contain data.
But if all OK, after submiting form conains all data.

I know how clear form with help of jQuery.
But how I make it in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your controller, after you have checked that your form is submitted and valid, and you have handled the data, you can try:

```
$form->reset();
```

in order to clean the form. More info in the ZF manual here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.values

Comment: You can also try <? = $this->formText ?> and use jQuery if you are lost.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this does not work in ZEND 2. See the code below to clear a form in ZEND 2

```
$elements = $form->getElements();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
  if ($element instanceof \Zend\Form\Element\Text) {
    $element->setValue('');
  }
  // Other element types here
}
```

[Credits](http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/zend-framework/clear-form-data-in-zf2)

Comment: What if I want to reset the form to its default values, instead of just empty values?

Comment: @Aise, create a new form object, reusing your original form variable.  As in... `$form = new YourFormClass();`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$form = new AlbumForm();
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost())
{
    $album = new Album();
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        /*
         * Process Form
         */
        ...

        /*
         * Create new Form
         */
        $form = new AlbumForm();
    }
}
```